# Importing/Appending Excel Files into Access Database using Power Automate

Tags: excel, ms-access, ssms, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I am currently new to Power Automate and am wondering if there is a way to import multiple Excel sheets (all same format/column names) into the same data table in Access using the append option, doing so through Power Automate. To my knowledge there is no connection between Power Automate and MS Access currently so if this is not possible, what would be my best option around it? I have about 1300 files to append into my Access database and am not wanting to do them one by one.

I also have SQL Server that I could create a database in but would prefer to somehow get it into Access.

Note: Appending the Excel sheets in Excel itself is not possible as all of the lists appended will be significantly over the max rows possible in Excel.

Comment: Access VBA can loop through files in folder and import. Common topic. Review http://accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_MainPage.htm